# Centos 7. php.ini error_reporting. Не работает

Tags: centos7, php.ini

Переношу проект с одного сервера на другой. На том сервере откуда переношу - все норм. Правда там установлен PHP 5.3.
На новом сервере PHP 5.5. Вот ошибка
https://prnt.sc/qhpj6y
Переменные в коде не определены. Нужно настроить игнор этих ошибок.
В /etc/php.ini прописал

```
error_reporting = E_ERROR & ~E_STRICT
```

Пробывал комментировать эту строчку полностью - эффекту никакого.
Перегружал fpm. Не помогает. В чем может быть причина? Как заигнорить ошибки?

Comment: php.ini: display_errors Off

Comment: Стоит, не помогает

Comment: display_errors = Off так прописано? Можете попробовать отключить тогда локально в файле php ini_set('error_reporting', 0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);

Comment: phpinfo() https://prnt.sc/qhq3il . Есть ли разница где прописываю ini_set('error_reporting', 0); ini_set('display_errors', 0); ? Прописал перед конфигами - не помогло. Никакого вообще эффекта